# SalesForce API Soap create() an Attachment on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, soap, salesforce

I started using the SalesForce SOAP API Enterprise on a project and I'm stuck on a create() method.

A lot of answers here on stackoverflow about this seems to be outdated, because the create() on this API doesn't receives only a SObject as it used to.

[image: Method Create]

I created all those objects but I'm having trouble on PackageVersion[] and LimitInfo[], I'm getting a null response from the server.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
        client = new SoapClient("Soap1", endpoint);
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT ID, CloseDate, StageName, Name FROM Opportunity";

        QueryResult qr = new QueryResult();
        client.query(header, null, null, null, sqlQuery, out qr);
        Attachment att = new Attachment();

        byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\teste.pdf");

        att.Body = pdf;
        att.Name = "Attachment Teste";
        att.Parent = qr.records[0];
        att.ParentId = qr.records[0].Id;                     

        DebuggingInfo debug = client.create(header, assignHeader, mruHeader, 
            allowField, disableFeed, streamingHeader, allOrNoneheader, duplicateHeader, 
            localeOptions, debugHeader, packVersion, emailHeader,new sObject[] { att },
            out limitInfo, out saveResult);
```

And I'm creating all those objects like this:

```
    private static SessionHeader header = new SessionHeader();
    private static AssignmentRuleHeader assignHeader = new AssignmentRuleHeader();
    private static MruHeader mruHeader = new MruHeader();
    private static AllowFieldTruncationHeader allowField = new    AllowFieldTruncationHeader();
    private static DisableFeedTrackingHeader disableFeed = new DisableFeedTrackingHeader();
    private static StreamingEnabledHeader streamingHeader = new StreamingEnabledHeader();
    private static AllOrNoneHeader allOrNoneheader = new AllOrNoneHeader();
    private static DuplicateRuleHeader duplicateHeader = new DuplicateRuleHeader();
    private static LocaleOptions localeOptions = new LocaleOptions();
    private static DebuggingHeader debugHeader = new DebuggingHeader();
    private static PackageVersion[] packVersion;
    private static EmailHeader emailHeader = new EmailHeader();
    private static LimitInfo[] limitInfo;
    private static SaveResult[] saveResult;
```

Can anyone tell me if there is another WSDL that has the create() with only the SObject as parameter?

If not, can anyone help with an example or an explanation on this create() method?

The documentation on salesforce.com seems to be outdated, because the create() method there only receives a SObject.

Thanks.

Comment: create a web reference, rather than a service reference (or alternatively you should be able to pass null for all the headers except session, which you'll need to populate correctly from a login call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this approach ?

```
SforceService binding = new SforceService();
binding.login("xxx", "yyy");
binding.SessionHeaderValue = new Service.SessionHeader();
binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = "sessionId";
binding.Url = "serverUrl";
binding = service.query(String.Format("select id, whoid...."))
var bindingSize = binding.size;
foreach (var sObject in binding.records) {...}
```

Comment: That worked. I needed to add the WSDL as a WebReference and used the SforceService as you said. Thanks.